# Sending a binary data over the network to the my sql database

Tags: android-networking, android-internet

I'm working on the application that will record the voice. I want those recordings to be stored in the external mysql database. I know that JSON works well with android and PHP that I can use to connect to DB but it works only with textual data. How can I accomplish this task?  What do you recommend to use to send the data? I will appreciate for a link of the good tutorial with examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are some different examples on the internet that explain how to use HTTP requests and networking on Android to communicate with a web server. Maybe you could start by looking at some of these http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidNetworking/article.html http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-android-networking/

Also, take a look at some of the articles here that talk about how to write a good networking app http://developer.att.com/developer/forward.jsp?passedItemId=7200042

Comment: Thanks for the response and the links. I will check all of them.